# JS: Print the value from index position, from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

This is my task that Im stuck on a bit:

> Write a function which receives two parameters, an array and an index.  The function will print the value of the element at the given position (one-based) to the console.
>
> For example, given the following array and index, the function will print `6`.
>
> ```
> var array = [3,6,67,6,23,11,100,8,93,0,17,24,7,1,33,45,28,33,23,12,99,100];
> var index = 1;
> ```

I managed to do the opposite, using `indexOf`, which prints the index position:

```
let index6 = array2.indexOf(6);
console.log(index6);
```

But I am not sure how to solve this.

Comment: The example doesn't match the instructions. It says the index is 1-based, so it should print `3`, not `6`.

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the question. You're supposed to use the index to find the value, not the other way around. A.e. `["a","b"][0]` will give you "a", `["a","b"][1]` will give you "b"

Comment: @zfrisch He knows that. He said his code does the opposite of what it asks.

Comment: @Barmar right, my mistake.

Comment: Think of the array as a street. Each element is a house and each house has an address (the index). If you are after the house "6" you just say visit the street at address 1. Something like array[1] is the "visit" syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just an ordinary array index:

```js
var array = [3, 6, 67, 6, 23, 11, 100, 8, 93, 0, 17, 24, 7, 1, 33, 45, 28, 33, 23, 12, 99, 100];
var index = 1;

function print_array_element(arr, i) {
  console.log(arr[i]);
}

print_array_element(array, index);
```

The instructions say that the index should be one-based, but that's not what the example does. If it should be one-based, subtract 1 from the index argument: `arr[i-1]`.

Comment: Yes, it was this easy (for you guys), but as a beginner I was stuck for a while. 

Thanks @Barmar ! 

not sure if there is a way to 'upvote' your answer in Stackoverflow....

Comment: When you get more rep you'll be able to upvote. But accepting the answer is the right thing for the questioner to do.